# Alternatives to loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I am looping an ecology database with over 600000 rows. One of these rows is "Species" but instead, it contains not only species names, but sometimes, when the species is not known, people wrote the class name, or the genus, or the order, etc.

I need to have the information properly organized in different rows, according to the taxonomic level of each bit of info, therefore I wrote a loop to assign taxonomic values to each row, taking the values from other rows in the same data frame which are indeed completed. The data, simplified, would look like this data frame:

```
data = data.frame(Latin_name = c("Gadus morhua", "Gadidae","Thalasoma pavo","Engraulis encrasicolus", "Gadiformes", "Actinopterygii"),
           Family  =c("Gadidae", "NA","Labridae", "Engraulidae", "NA", "NA"),
           Order = c("Gadiformes", "NA", "Labriformes", "Clupeiformes", "NA", "NA"), 
           Class = c("Actinopterygii","NA","Actinopterygii","Actinopterygii", "NA", "NA"))
```

And the loop that I am using to assign the columns with NAs, is this:

```
for (row in 1:nrow(data)) {
  if ((data$Latin_name[row] %in% data$Family) == TRUE) {
  
  data$Family[row] = data$Family[which(data$Family == data$Latin_name[row])][1]
  data$Order[row]  = data$Order[which(data$Family  == data$Latin_name[row])][1]
  data$Class[row]  = data$Class[which(data$Family  == data$Latin_name[row])][1]
  } else if ((data$Latin_name[row] %in% data$Class) == TRUE) {
    
    data$Family[row] = data$Family[which(data$Class == data$Latin_name[row])][1]
    data$Order[row]  = data$Order[which(data$Class  == data$Latin_name[row])][1]
    data$Class[row]  = data$Class[which(data$Class  == data$Latin_name[row])][1]
    
  } else if ((data$Latin_name[row] %in% data$Order) == TRUE) {
    
    data$Family[row] = data$Family[which(data$Order == data$Latin_name[row])][1]
    data$Order[row]  = data$Order[which(data$Order  == data$Latin_name[row])][1]
    data$Class[row]  = data$Class[which(data$Order  == data$Latin_name[row])][1]
  }
}
```

Can any of you think of a faster way to do it? This loop takes more than 10 h to run :'(

Comment: Please provide a complete reproducible example.  See the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page for info on asking questions.

Comment: The if statements should start on separate lines and the example data is such that the loop does not change data at all. Maybe you can come up with a better example.

Comment: Now it does exactly what I meant. Thank you very much and sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: In row 6 where only `Actinopterygii` is given, your code outputs that the Family and Order are `Gadidae, Gadiformes`, but it could equally be `Engraulidae, Clupeiformes` or `Labridae, Labriformes` or `Engraulidae, Clupeiformes`, right?

Comment: Just curious how many distinct combinations there are? Right now you have it searching all 60K rows more than one time in each if statement. It may be better to create a distinct combination data frame for it to search instead of all 60K rows.

Comment: What do you mean? To create a separate data frame with only those rows that are missing tax info? This is a great idea, I will try it out, thank you!

Comment: It did not work, because I need reference columns to complete those incomplete ones...

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid loops in R. Instead, it is much more recommended to use dplyr / tidyverse for what you intend to do. I think the approach would be something like this (corrections are appreciated, since I haven't used R in a while).

```
parsedData <- data %>% group_by(*variable name you would like to group*) %>% summarise(
   newVariable = *the components of your new variable*
)
```

However, the most important thing is to avoid loops. In case you need to loop something big, you could also take a look to sapply, apply, lapply, and mapply functions.

Comment: Yeah, I always try to avoid looping, but the thing is that I do not know how to take values from another row, and to add them in each row, without looping :(

Comment: In dplyr when creating a new variable, simply reference the variable that you like. For example, imagine that I have a dataset with columns x and y. Then, if I'd like to have a third column, you could do this:
data <- data %>% mutate ( z = x + y ). Moreover, you could also use conditionals:
data <- data %>% mutate ( z = ifelse(x > k, x + y, x - y))

Comment: yeah, but can i refer to the same row, when using conditional? Can I write : 

" If the value of this row's column X is in any other row's column Y, then take the column X of this other row and put it in the current row". 

?

Comment: Yes. Actually, you don't need to think in rows, since dplyr does that work for you. Simply think in variables (columns).

Answer (score 1):

```
data2 = data
data2[data2 == "NA"] = NA

rownames(data2) = 1:nrow(data2)

cleanData = data2[rowSums(!is.na(data2)) >= 4,]FamilyKey = setNames(cleanData[,2],cleanData[,1])
OrderKey = setNames(cleanData[,3],cleanData[,2])
ClassKey = setNames(cleanData[,4],cleanData[,3])

data3 = data2[rowSums(!is.na(data2)) < 4,]

# step 1: label to the right: label Family, Order and Class from Latin_name where missing
data3[data3$Latin_name %in% (FamilyKey),]$Family = revalue(data3[data3$Latin_name %in% (FamilyKey),]$Latin_name, FamilyKey)
data3[data3$Latin_name %in% (OrderKey),]$Order = revalue(data3[data3$Latin_name %in% (OrderKey),]$Latin_name, OrderKey)
data3[data3$Latin_name %in% (ClassKey),]$Class = revalue(data3[data3$Latin_name %in% (ClassKey),]$Latin_name, ClassKey)

#step 2: label to the right again: label order from family and class from order
data3[data3$Family %in% (FamilyKey),]$Order = revalue(data3[data3$Family %in% (FamilyKey),]$Family, OrderKey)
data3[data3$Order %in% (OrderKey),]$Class = revalue(data3[data3$Order %in% (OrderKey),]$Order, ClassKey)

# combine together are reorder to original order
data2 = rbind(cleanData, data3)
data2 = data2[ order(rownames(data2)) , ,drop=F]
```

Your output:

```
> data
              Latin_name      Family        Order          Class Other_cols
1           Gadus morhua     Gadidae   Gadiformes Actinopterygii          x
2                Gadidae     Gadidae   Gadiformes Actinopterygii         NA
3         Thalasoma pavo    Labridae  Labriformes Actinopterygii          x
4 Engraulis encrasicolus Engraulidae Clupeiformes Actinopterygii          x
5             Gadiformes     Gadidae   Gadiformes Actinopterygii         NA
6         Actinopterygii     Gadidae   Gadiformes Actinopterygii         NA
```

My output:

```
> data2
              Latin_name      Family        Order          Class Other_cols
1           Gadus morhua     Gadidae   Gadiformes Actinopterygii          x
2                Gadidae     Gadidae   Gadiformes Actinopterygii       <NA>
3         Thalasoma pavo    Labridae  Labriformes Actinopterygii          x
4 Engraulis encrasicolus Engraulidae Clupeiformes Actinopterygii          x
5             Gadiformes        <NA>   Gadiformes Actinopterygii       <NA>
6         Actinopterygii        <NA>         <NA> Actinopterygii       <NA>
```

I assume strictly that Family < Order < Class